# How to call JavaScript functions from Rails views?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have JavaScript functions which popup the new screen and I need to use them in a Rails view.

This is the script in `/app/assets/signup.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function popup() {
    cuteLittleWindow = window.open("signup.html", "littleWindow", "location=no,width=320,height=200");
  }

</script>
```

How can I use JavaScript functions in my `/views/index.html.erb`?

Comment: Just put same code including `<script>` tags in your `index.html.erb` file

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code before the closing body tag like this:

```
<body>
  <!-- Your body things -->

  <script>

  $(function(){

    function popup(){ 
      cuteLittleWindow = window.open("signup.html", "littleWindow", "location=no,width=320,height=200"); 
    }

  });

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: In this way, the function will be available on every page, even it is intended to be used only on a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

**in index.html.erb**

```
#####your view code

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  function popup(){ 
    cuteLittleWindow = window.open("signup.html", "littleWindow", "location=no,width=320,height=200"); 
  }

})//document ends
</script>
```

With Rails [`turbolinks`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks) you have to listen on `turbolinks:load` event:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```